# sqoop-import-mainframe large datasets

Tags: hadoop, ftp, sqoop, mainframe

I am trying to import mainframe datasets into hdfs using [sqoop-import-mainframe](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_import_mainframe_literal). The sqoop command is executed from oozie.

```
<action name="sqoop-load">
    <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <prepare>
            <delete path="${nameNode}/test-sqoop"/>
        </prepare>
        <command>import-mainframe --connect zhostname --username USERNAME --password PASSWORD --dataset AAAA.BBBB.CCCC.DDDD --target-dir ${nameNode}/test-sqoop -m 1 --verbose</command>
    </sqoop>
    <ok to="End"/>
    <error to="Kill"/>
</action>
```

The command ends succesfully (the txt file is created on hdfs) only if the input file is smaller than 500 MB. If i try to import files that are greater than 500 MB the sqoop action does not start and i get this error:

> 220-FTPD1 IBM FTP CS V2R1 at zhostname, 14:26:24 on 2017-03-28.
>       220 Connection will close if idle for more than 30 minutes.
>       4606 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.util.MainframeFTPClientUtils  - Connected to zhostname on 21
>       USER *******
>       331 Send password please.
>       PASS *******
>       230 USERNAME is logged on.  Working directory is "USERNAME.".
>       TYPE A
>       200 Representation type is Ascii NonPrint
>       CWD 'AAAA.BBBB.CCCC.DDDD'
>       250 "AAAA.BBBB.CCCC.DDDD." is the working directory name prefix.
>       PASV
>       227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,20,1,123,54)
>       LIST
>       125 List started OK
>       250 List completed successfully.
>       NOOP
>       200 OK
>       QUIT
>       221 Quit command received. Goodbye.
>       4688 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool  - Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: No sequential datasets retrieved from AAAA.BBBB.CCCC.DDDD
>       at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.mainframe.MainframeDatasetInputFormat.getSplits(MainframeDatasetInputFormat.java:65)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:305)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:322)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:200)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1307)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1304)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1709)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1304)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1325)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.doSubmitJob(ImportJobBase.java:203)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:176)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:273)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MainframeManager.importTable(MainframeManager.java:97)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:507)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:615)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
>       at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.runSqoopJob(SqoopMain.java:197)
>       at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.run(SqoopMain.java:177)
>       at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:49)
>       at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.main(SqoopMain.java:46)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:236)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1709)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

I'm sure the dataset exists.

The environment is Cloudera CDH 5.8.3, am I missing some configuration?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you FTP the file down?

Comment: Yes, I can download the large dataset with FTP.

Comment: Looks like there is a limit in your sloop or uzi.